# How to obtain a part of a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, dimensional

Suppose if I have a 4x4 array matrix like

```
aaaa
abba
abba
aaaa
```

Can I obtain a 3x3 matrix from the above matrix and store it in another 2d array. The 3x3 matrix should contain the elements

```
aaa
abb
abb
```

likewise

```
aaa
bba
bba
```

and two more matrices.

Can this be done using Arrays.copyOfRange ??

EDIT: I also want the other 2 3x3 matrices ie.

```
abb
abb
aaa
```

and

```
bba
bba
aaa
```

Like if I pass the elements in the 2x2 matrix which in the 4x4 ie. b's , it should give me a 3x3 matrix surrounding the element.

I can make this happen by using a for loop which takes the i and j values from subtracting 1 from the index of the element ( here 'b')  which I'm passing , which results in a 3x3 matrix surrounding the value b ( given above ) . But just want to know if there is an easier way.

Comment: Perhaps you could first (a) read the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(byte[],%20int,%20int), (b) Give it a try.  If this does not work for you, then post the code you have tried with your specific problem.

Comment: Yes, I saw the documentation. But I could find that copyofrange can obtain data from a single dimensional array. I want to know how it can done for a 2d array. I can use the centre 2x2 in the 4x4 matrix and get the elements surrounding each element of the 2x2 to get the required 3x3 array using for loops . Just wanted to know if there is an easy way.

Comment: If you added some more information about what you are going to do with these sub-arrays, one might give further hints. For example, you might consider an `interface Array2D { ... }` that has a method `Array2D getSubArray(...)` that only returns a *view* on the sub-array. Many solutions are possible here, and some might be more elegant than copying, depending on the application case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use System.lang.arrayCopy:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayRange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[][] original = createMatrix(4);

        // copy 3x3 array starting at 1,0
        char[][] subArray = copySubrange(original, 1, 0, 3, 3);

        printArray(original);
        printArray(subArray);
    }

    private static char[][] copySubrange(char[][] source, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (source.length == 0) {
            return new char[0][0];
        }
        if (height < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("height must be positive");
        }
        if (width < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("width must be positive");
        }
        if ((y + height) > source.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("subrange too high");
        }
        char[][] dest = new char[height][width];
        for (int destY = 0; destY < height; destY++) {
            char[] srcRow = source[(y + destY)];
            if ((x + width) > srcRow.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("subrange too wide");
            }
            System.arraycopy(srcRow, x, dest[destY], 0, width);
        }
        return dest;
    }

    // Set up a matrix as an array of rows.
    // The y-coordinate is the position of a row in the array.
    // The x-coordinate is the position of an element in a row.
    private static char[][] createMatrix(int size) {
        char[][] original = new char[size][size];
        for (int y = 0; y < original.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < original[0].length; x++) {
                original[y][x] = (char) (Math.random() * 10 + 48);
            }
        }
        return original;
    }

    private static void printArray(char[][] array) {
        for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[y]));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
[0, 7, 4, 3]
[9, 2, 7, 2]
[9, 2, 4, 0]
[9, 1, 5, 9]

[7, 4, 3]
[2, 7, 2]
[2, 4, 0]
```

EDIT: improved code with range checks.

Comment: yes ! this is what I needed. Thanks alot :) The range checks which you have mentioned is to avoid getting an array out of bounds exception right?

Comment: Correct, and you can check to avoid npe's